# Tab spacing effect with HTML or CSS

Tags: html, css, formatting

I'm building a personal website and I would like a tab-like (as used word processors) effect for projects and their respective descriptions. Example display:

```
ReallyLong NameProject     Project1 Description 
FooBar Project             Project2 Description
```

I've tried a table solution with cell spacing of 10px but I didn't want spacing on all sides, just to the right. I haven't seen any css examples where cell spacing was only applied to the right side. Is it possible?

I've also tried this in the css file(it had no effect):

```
table {
padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: And what mark-up are you trying to style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of styling the table with padding, which should do nothing, try applying it to the td elements in the table like this:

```
table td {
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try applying the padding to the td element, and not the whole table element.